# How to paginate my table of products using jsp servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, html-table, pagination

This my jsp file and it list elements of a database of products in a table , 3 product for each line, and I want to paginate my list so that after  4 or 5 lines I can click the next page to continue listing the remaining products. Any help  would be appreciated, I searched too much but I couldn't find something easy to understand, so here is my code if anyone can give the solution:

```
<table>
<%
int numberofcolumns=4;int cmp =0;int cm_image = 4;int cm_price =5;int cmp_category =6;int cmp_quantity =7;
 while (cmp<=size ) // cmp is an counter, and size is the size of the products array 
{ 

c++;

if (c==numberofcolumns){
    numberofcolumns=numberofcolumns+3;  
out.println("<tr>"); // for that each line countain 3 columns (products)

}

out.println("<td>");

out.println("<p><img src=\"images/" + Arrayp.get(cm_image) + " \" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" /></p>");
 out.println("<p> prix  "   +Arrayp.get(cm_price) + "</p>"); 
out.println("<p>" + Arrayp.get(cmp_category) + "</p>");
out.println("<p>quantité disponible " + Arrayp.get(cmp_quantity) + "</p>"); 

cmpcounter=cmpcounter+8; //because my database (array) contains 8 columns on each line
cm_image=cm_image+8;
cm_price=cm_price+8;
cmp_category=cmp_category+8;
cmp_quantity=cmp_quantity+8;
out.println("<td>");
}
out.println("</tr>");
%>

  </table>
```

Comment: I can give you just suggestion, I have mobile phone only now. What you need is to create a link to next page with parameter, say FROM, where you pass index of next element to continue. Your jsp will read this parameter and skip elements before this index. Personally I do not like Java code within jsp - scriptlet. The code is hard to read. Google for jsp standard tag library, it may help you. And before you start writing some code, write your algorithm on paper - it will force you to really think of the problem. This is necessary for pagination part.

Comment: Start by using a for loop rather than while loop `for(int i=0; i<Arrayp.size(); i++)` and then figure out from there how to limit it to what you want.